# Vue 3 CLI jest testing - MatchInlineSnapshot does not work?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, vue-cli, ts-jest

I am having an issue with my Vue project where ToMatchInline Snapshot does not work and fails test
[image: Result of test]

Any ideas?

Here's my config file
[image: Is also a typescript project]

I also tried with render from @testing-library/vue and still getting the same... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was writing the question I figured it out. I needed a snapshot serializer:

ran `npm i -D jest-serializer-vue`

and added the following line to my `jest.config.js`

`snapshotSerializers: ["jest-serializer-vue"]`

so it now looks as so

[image]